# Non Kähler blow-up of a Kähler manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Is it possible to find a complete, non compact Kahler manifold $(X,\omega)$ with a closed, connected, non compact complex submanifold $Y\subset X$ of codimension at least 2 such that the blow-up of $X$ along $Y$  is not Kähler?

Comment: See Lemma 34 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9502002.pdf

Answer (score 4):

When $Y$ is compact, the blow-up is always Kahler;
see e.g. Lemma 3.4 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4885)
(this is a generally known folklore theorem which we 
had to use, and hence written down).

For $Y$ non-compact the argument should be similar, but more cumbersome.

Comment: Hi, i know that if $Y$ is compact then blow up is Kahler but to construct the metric on $Bl_{Y}X$ substantially you use $\pi^{*}\omega+\varepsilon c_{1}(\mathcal{O}(-E))$ where $E$ is the exceptional divisor and $\pi: Bl_{Y}X\rightarrow X$ is the canonical surjection. But the delicate thing is that the threshold $\varepsilon$ for which the above is a metric is bounded from below when $Y$ is compact, but is no longer obvious (at least to me) when $Y$ is not compact.

Comment: Same argument works, I think (I just checked, don't see any problems)